# What is the best alternate to Pidgin under Linux?

Tags: linux, pidgin, jabber

Pidgin (2.5.5) keeps crashing on me (Ubuntu 9.04).  What is the best alternative to it that supports XMPP/Jabber as well as MSN & Yahoo?

Comment: Pidgin, the g isn't capitalized.

Comment: Pidgin is up to 2.6.2, which I know fixed at least one crash condition.

Comment: @mwalling: thanks for the info: it seems that the Ubuntu repos do not have it (2.6.2) yet.

Comment: But there are Pidgin's own repos, instructions at http://pidgin.im/download/ubuntu/

Comment: @grawity: Thanks!  I should have guessed and not only rely on Ubuntu aptitude.

Comment: 10 more crash bugs closed in 2.6.4 http://developer.pidgin.im/query?status=closed&summary=~crash&col=id&col=summary&col=status&col=owner&col=type&col=milestone&milestone=2.6.4&order=priority

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For KDE users, [Kopete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopete) is an excellent alternative.  [Empathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathy_(software)) is also quite good and seems to be improving at a fast clip. [Psi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psi_(instant_messaging_client)) natively supports only XMPP, but can connect to other major networks via gateways.

Comment: Kopete is more lenient than Empathy when it comes to communicating with chat bots (ones that don't implement the IQ disco protocols).

Answer (score 5):

[Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy) has been getting alot of attention recently.  Works on about as many networks as pidgin, but it lacks several of the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

As I've said [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/questions/20440/mac-os-x-irc-clients/20446#20446), I use a combination of [irssi](http://irssi.org) and [BitlBee](http://bitlbee.org) for my instant messaging needs.

It isn't flashy like a desktop IM client.

Quadpoint has lots of different articles about using Irssi [here](http://quadpoint.org/works).

Answer (score 1):

[Kopete](http://kopete.kde.org/), P[si](http://psi-im.org/) and [Gossip](http://www.semsoftware.com/gossip/index.htm) are 3 good options for you. [Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy) is new, if you've time for testing it out you can try that as well. Other options :([irssi](http://quadpoint.org/articles/irssi),[Bitbee](http://www.bitlbee.org/)), it depends your needs though.

Comment: Links would have been nice: googling for 'Gossip' is sort of time intensive-ish.

Comment: Links to Gossip,Empathy,Bitbee are now added :)

Comment: Gossip is Windows only it seems.......

Comment: There is linux version as well. It is in repository of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I know you want alternatives, the best is probably empathy, but i wouldn't switch away until you've updated to the latest version (which has working XMPP Video and audio in ubuntu) 
I think an update will fix your problems, if not:
Empathy
Kopete
Psi
[Coccinella](http://thecoccinella.org/)
Jabbin
Gajim
I think this might work too
[emesene](http://www.emesene.org/)